# Disable Account&Contact autopopulate on Case for Partner Community

Tags: case, account, partner-portal, partner-communities

Currently when I create a Case using my Partner Community licensed user in our Communities my Contact is set as Contact on Case and my parent Account of that Contact is set as the Account on the Case. In my setup this is not desired and I would prefer if no Contact/Account is set on the Case once it is created, unless specified by the user of course. I have written a trigger that handles this but I want to know if there is a standard setting I am just not seeing? Which would remove the autopopulation of Contact/Account, from the User creating the Case, on the Case.